# Substr not allowing double digit codes to process on form

Tags: php, substr

I have an array that uses two codes in a list and pushes them into a form on the next page. Currently I have:

```
            $code= array();
            $code['c1'] = substr($part, 0, 1);
            $code['c2'] = substr($part, 2);
```

Now, If I select anything with a single digit `c1` and single or double `c2` then it adds to the form.

Examples:

```
1-9
1-15
9-12
9-9
```

But if I try to add anything with double digits in c1 it doesn't add, like:

```
10-1
10-2
10-11
```

If I try

```
$codes= array();
$codes['c1'] = substr($part, 0, 2);
$codes['c2'] = substr($part, 2);
```

Then no codes show up.

How can I account for both?

UPDATE:

Currently, the above code, if I select 10-58, will dump c1 as 1 and c2 as -5

Comment: What is `$part`, and how are the values in the array used in the form?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "no codes show up"?  Using "10-11" the result is "10" in `c1` and "-11" in `c2`?  What result do you expect with that input?  Maybe you just want to change `substr($part, 2)` to `substr($part, 3)`?

Comment: @PatrickQ sorry for the confusion, but in the above examples I would want the form to reflect 10-1,10-2 and 10-11 exactly the same way

Comment: But what is that way?  You've neglected to show what your desired output is for the given inputs.

Comment: You should use 2 fields as you have 2 codes. But if you want to combine them like you are doing now, just use `explode()` instead.

Comment: @PatrickQ on the first page the code shows as 10-11, so when I post it to the page that uses the above function, I want it in the field to show as 10-11 as well.

Comment: @TomN. If you have "10-11" in `$parts` and you want to output "10-11", then you would simply `echo $parts`.  If that is _not_ what you want, then you need to provide more code context in your question to show what's _actually_ goin on.

Comment: @PatrickQ I updated my code loop and the new outputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to split any combination of codes...

```
$part = "1-15";
$codes = array();
list($codes['c1'], $codes['c2']) = explode("-", $part);
print_r($codes);
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [c1] => 1
    [c2] => 15
)
```

For

```
$part = "10-15";
```

it gives...

```
Array
(
    [c1] => 10
    [c2] => 15
)
```

If you are unsure if your data is always correct, you can check that the data has 2 components after using `explode()` and only convert it then, you can also do something to report and error or whatever you need...

```
$split = explode("-", $part);
if ( count($split) == 2 ){
    $codes['c1'] = $split[0];
    $codes['c2'] = $split[1];
}
else    {
    // Not of correct format.
}

print_r($codes);
```

Comment: I see what's going on in your answer, and I actually updated my question with more code context. Is there a way to keep the structure I have above but still acount for either 1 or 2 digits on either side of the '-' ?

Comment: You mean as in the example I've included of `$part = "10-15";`?

Comment: Right, but your last example using $split, will that keep a similar structure to what I have?

Comment: It produces the same results as the other examples but just adds a bit of resilience and shouldn't error if the input code is wrong

Comment: @TomN. Why is this answer not accepted?  You should not be using substr, you should be using explode.